# Is there something wrong with this code? Or my computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner with Python and coding in general, but whenever I try to run the below code it either just, almost freezes and doesn't run the program or it will run the program and ignore this piece? Or leave it blank where it should be? I'm very confused

```
cubed_numbers = list(range(1, 11))
for value in cubed_numbers:
    cubed_numbers.append(value ** 3)
print(value)
```

Comment: If you insert a "print" statement in you loop, you may be able to see and understand better what happens (i.e., python does exactly what you tell him to do, no "mysterious bug" or "something wrong with your computer")

Comment: I understand that, but the indentation in this case would mean Python completes its looping process, and THEN prints it out, just the once, would it not?

Comment: if the print is "in the loop body" (indented), it will execute for each iteration of the loop. If you write it _unindented_ as you did above, after the loop body, it will print only after the loop is over (which actually never happens in your code, so you won't see anything in the latter case)

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently appending to the same list that you are cubing on. It might be a better idea to create a new list instead to avoid an infinite loop.

EDIT: Something similar to this

```
cubed_numbers = []
for value in list(range(1, 11)):
    cubed_numbers.append(value ** 3)
print(cubed_numbers) # Also, I guess you want to print the cubed_numbers since this is out of the for loop.
```

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: Gotta wrap my head around it, but this helps greatly, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your computer.

You are modifying (appending) the list as you try to iterate through it.  Basically, you never finish the loop because you keep adding more before it finishes.

In general, it is a pretty bad idea to mutate a list (or other mutable object) as you iterate through it.

Maybe you meant something like this instead:

```
cubed_nums = [value**3 for value in range(1,11)]
print(cubed_nums)
```

output:

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a particular reason then for how the code below ran okay, but the code in this post did not? ' squares = [ ]
for value in range(1, 11):
 squares.append(value ** 2)
print(squares) '

Comment: `range(1,11)` (the list being iterated over) doesn't change size in the loop in the code above, whereas `cubed_numbers` is being modified in the original case

Comment: Very confusing, but I'll get there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code and run:

```
cubed_numbers = list(range(1, 11))
for value in cubed_numbers:
    cubed_numbers.append(value ** 3)
    print(len(cubed_numbers))
    print(cubed_numbers)
    if value == 10:
        break
print(cubed_numbers)
```

You create infinity loop 'for value in cubed_numbers'.
In next iteration your list get new value and your loop have new iteration.

Comment: Please do not post code without explanation

Answer (score 0):

`.append` *modifies* the existing list.

*Do not loop* on a collection that you are modifiying!

Here you add something at each iteration, so the loop will never end.

Instead, you probably want one list to loop over, and another list to store results. There is also more idiomatic constructs in python like "list comprehension".

Comment: Thank you! I'm just beginning to learn about list comprehension

Comment: see [anon01's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367729/479251) for an example of list comprehension.